# Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar' in update ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

Very simple question but all the answer I read over the web doesn't apply.

I try to do an update on a ASP.NET Gridview but when I click on update, I get this error:

Incorrect Syntax near 'nvarchar'. The scalar variable @intID must be declare.

Here is my datasource. I guess the problem come from here but I can't see where...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connexionDev %>"  
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tbl_Bug] WHERE intID = @intID" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [intID],[strTitre],[strDescription],[intStatus_FK],[intType_FK],[intSeriousness_FK] FROM [tbl_Bug]"  
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_Bug] SET [strTitre] = @strTitre ,[strDescription] = @strDescription ,[intStatus_FK] = @intStatus_FK ,[intType_FK] = @intType_FK ,[intSeriousness_FK] = @intSeriousness_FK WHERE [intID] = @intID">   
        <DeleteParameters>   
            <asp:Parameter Name="intID" Type="Int32" />   
        </DeleteParameters>   
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="intID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="strTitre" Type="String" />   
            <asp:Parameter Name="strDescription" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="intStatus_FK" Type="Int32" />   
            <asp:Parameter Name="intType_FK" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="intSeriousness_FK" Type="Int32" />   
        </UpdateParameters>     
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

EDIT - EDIT - EDIT

Well, I wanted to use SQL Profiler but it seems that it's not in my version (SQL server 2008 Express) so I tried another sql profiler that is open source but I never understood how it worked and it was always crashing ...

Is there any other way to know the query that are used so I can track my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi everyone and thanks for your help

My query was good, it was the binding in the `GridView` that was bad, for a very very simple detail

This will work:   `Text='<%# Bind("myValue") %>'`

While this wont:   `Text='<%# Bind("[myValue]") %>'`

So watch out! :) Now everything is working!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this the answer is often to run SQL Profiler and see what SQL is being sent, it's often a mismatch in variable names or something equally simple once you see what being sent to your SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can register an event handler for `SqlDataSource.Updating` event - it will be raised when the command is prepared, and before executing it. The command will be a `DbCommand` object, which can be retrieved from an instance of `SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs` that your event handler will get via its `Command` property. Dump both the text, and the actual names and values of all command parameters (in `DbCommand.Parameters` collection), and check it for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `<SelectParameters>...</SelectParameters>` section where you declare all your fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is always the case when you have spaces in your field/column  names - rename the DB columns and remove spaces - it will work .

If you look at the SQL server monitor and inspect  the generated SQL code for Update - it is messed up due to spaces in column names.